# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

My environment:

```
# uname -a
Linux app11 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# 
# cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
#
```

while trying to run `apt-get update`, I get bunch of errors:

```
# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease           
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release 
Get:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease [6,377 B]
Ign:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable InRelease
Hit:8 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable Release
Get:9 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease [3,843 B]
Get:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease [3,876 B]
Hit:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Err:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
Err:9 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
Err:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
Fetched 6,377 B in 0s (7,132 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/cloud-sdk-stretch/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/google-compute-engine-stretch-stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
#
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Per [Installing Google Cloud SDK  |  Cloud SDK Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions) - Debian/Ubuntu:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

OR

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

follow by:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: mark for right answer man!

Comment: On my system I get this output: `gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0`

Comment: Same error, `NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071 NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB`. That's because `google-cloud-sdk.list` has `[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg]`. So you should update that keyring instead of the default one.

Comment: The 2nd one wasn't working for me, but the 1st one did. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

Comment: it's same as my answer...

Comment: When using @alexus method, I get `(23) Failed writing body`, however this worked for me.

Comment: Using @alexus method fail but this one work on Ubuntu Focal. It's look like `--keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg`  make the difference.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Eventually I noticed that to install the google sdk I used the following, copied directly from the google documentation:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Eventually I noticed that `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` had a reference to a gpg file, which I thought might be the offending "NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB" mismatch:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

When I went to open the gpg file (`/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg`) it didn't exist. So I edited `google-cloud-sdk.list` to remove the reference:

```
deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

And after that, I was able to update with `apt-get update` without issue.

### Slightly off topic - fixing previous google sdk install

Then I remembered that installed the google sdk and kubectl using snap, because I got an error, and I hoped this might fix it. The installer suggested snap when it couldn't find the proper repositories.

My original install commands:

```
snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic
snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic
```

So, I removed the snap versions and installed the regular versions.

```
snap remove google-cloud-sdk
snap remove kubectl
sudo apt-get install kubectl
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Comment: Thank you, editing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In ubuntu 22+

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked with Debain Bookworm

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error:

```
Err:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

None of these answers worked for me.

I ended up having to delete the google cloud entry from my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list*
```

And this deleted the following entries for me:

```
google-cloud-sdk.list
google-cloud-sdk.list.distUpgrade
google-cloud-sdk.list.save
```

For your situation, you may need to find and delete the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` entries that correspond to `cloud-sdk-stretch`.

Answer (score 0):

The official google documentation has the answer to this:

> Troubleshooting Tip: If your distribution does not support the
> signed-by option run this command instead:
>
> ```
> echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
> ```

See Debian/Ubuntu > Installation (last paragraph): https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but on ubuntu 20.04 that I stood up in Azure I had to switch using `curl` to `wget`:

```
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg 
cat apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer doesn't work in my case (debian container), This is the command I had to run for it to work (found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/13132)):

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B57C5C2836F4BEB  FEEA9169307EA071
```

Answer (score -1):

On your terminal:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

**Sources**

- [Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

The following command works for me as of May 2021:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

Source: [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/zeGb4gdK2Iw?pli=1) the gce-discussion Google Groups board

Answer (score -1):

Problem was all about updating Key with GCP (this problem come for Ubuntu running on Google Cloud Platform). so to updating Public key is required :

Following Cmd update the Key (i.e register Ubuntu with GCP server) :

> curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

### Update Key in machine (Refresh)

> sudo apt get update

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! How is your answer different from the accepted answer?

Comment: hey  @Paul  I wanted to upvote the accepted answer, but since I don't have that reputation (for now), so added as answer.
Thank You for noticing

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get clean
apt update --fix-missing
```

Comment: it works for me, why negative note !

Comment: What's with the missing command: sudo apt-key add -... There's something missing there, I think.

Comment: it was already answered, in the same way.

Answer (score -3):

I had similar problem, but nothing worked for me except of this

```
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```